# How to sort modules in config.php alphabetically?

Tags: magento2, module, sorting

Is it possible to sort the output of the modules node in `config.php` alphabetically? This way git versioning won't get messed up since Magento sometimes changes the sorting.

```
<?php
return [
    'modules' => [
        'Magento_ModuleA' => 1,
        'Magento_ModuleB' => 1,
        'Magento_ModuleC' => 1,
        ...
```

`composer.json` has an option for it, is there something similar for `config.php`?

```
"config": {
        "sort-packages": true
```

Answer (score 1):

We can control the module load order using the sequence tag in module.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_ComponentB" setup_version="0.0.1">
        <sequence>
        <!-- Vendor_ComponentB is dependent on Vendor_ComponentA: -->
            <module name="Vendor_ComponentA" />
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

**Easy for your reference:** https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/build/module-load-order.html

> If you change the component load order using `sequence`, you must
> regenerate the component list in config.php; otherwise, the load order
> does not take effect. Currently, the only way to do this is to enable
> the component using Magento module: enable, where `module list is the
> component or components to which you added .

**Note:** Don't sort/change the core module load order, it will create issues. For example, **core-module-a** depends on **core-module-b**, **core-module-a** will not work properly if you didn't load **core-module-b** first.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to sort the output of the modules node in `config.php` alphabetically?

The simple answer is no. The order of files in config.php is determined by the module load sequence in @Bilal's answer. This is critical to Magento's internal module loading logic and also sets the order in which configuration XML files are loaded and merged allowing DI, events, and all the other XML files in your `etc` directory, to modify other modules configuration.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple open source module for keeping sorting same for config.php here - https://github.com/zero1limited/magento2-PreserveModuleOrderingInProductionMode.